# Set DM on OpenRC

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, display-manager, openrc

How do I set a display manager on an [OpenRC](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:OpenRC) system? I'm trying to use the Ly display manager.

E.g. on a systemd distro I'd do

```
$ sudo systemctl enable ly.service
```

but how do I do it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, with OpenRC you add a service starting on boot with:

`rc-update add $service default`, where $service is a init file coded for OpenRC.
Is located in /etc/init.d/$service and is invoked by `#!/sbin/openrc-run`, that is the directive at the beginning of the service file.

[Here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Writing_Init_Scripts) you can figure how to write a openrc init script by yourself.

.: Francesco

Comment: One remark: I'd say "after boot" to avoid confusion, since `boot` is another runlevel, not `default`. To start service "on boot" the command should be `rc-update add $service boot`. See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Initscripts#Writing_initscripts